# Missing dependency ‘object scala.native in compiler mirror’

Tags: scala, java-native-interface, scala-compiler, runtime-compilation

I used scala-compiler.jar to compile an embedded Scala program
This scala program imports a class written using jni

- The code is as follows

```
class test{
  def test(ctx: ContractContext): ActionResult = {
    val s = new DllTest
    s.loadLibrary()
    print(s.intMethod(5))
    null
  }
}
```

DllTest is a jni application

- The error is as follows

```
error: error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala.native in compiler mirror', required by /modules/java.base/java/lang/Object.class

Failed to initialize compiler: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

Anyone knows the reason? And how to solve the problem?

It works fine in the main function

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //Create system instance
    val s = new DllTest
    s.loadLibrary()
    print(s.intMethod(5))
......
```

Comment: Connected discussion https://users.scala-lang.org/t/missing-dependency-object-scala-native-in-compiler-mirror/9162

Answer (score 2):

According to

[object scala in compiler mirror not found - running Scala compiler programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934282/object-scala-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-running-scala-compiler-programmatica)

["scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found" but working when started with -Xbootclasspath/p:scala-library.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150961/scala-runtime-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-but-working-when-started-with-xboo)

[Why am I getting "object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found." with scala-maven-plugin when dependency is upgraded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63273289/why-am-i-getting-object-scala-runtime-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-with-scala)

[object scala in compiler mirror not found - running Scala compiler programatically [no sbt - no IDE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911848/object-scala-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-running-scala-compiler-programatical)

most probably you should try to switch on `settings.usejavacp.value = true` as written in the error message. How to feed this setting to the compiler depends on how you run it.

See examples how to run the compiler programmatically in

[Exception while compiling scala code from Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705335/exception-while-compiling-scala-code-from-java-program/)

[How to compile and execute scala code at run-time in Scala3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945320/how-to-compile-and-execute-scala-code-at-run-time-in-scala3)

[How can I run generated code during script runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911801/how-can-i-run-generated-code-during-script-runtime)

[Scala reflection: compile akka actor with protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302376/scala-reflection-compile-akka-actor-with-protobuf)

[Dynamic compilation of multiple Scala classes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922911/dynamic-compilation-of-multiple-scala-classes-at-runtime)

[How to eval code that uses InterfaceStability annotation (that fails with "illegal cyclic reference involving class InterfaceStability")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976254/how-to-eval-code-that-uses-interfacestability-annotation-that-fails-with-illeg)

[Tensorflow in Scala reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783153/tensorflow-in-scala-reflection)

[dynamically parse json in flink map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111895/dynamically-parse-json-in-flink-map/)

Comment: I noticed an open ticket about classpaths which started as a clash of `--release 8` and `-javabootclasspath`. So many options, so many class loaders, so many build tools. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/10336

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, I have set the appropriate options in my code

```
val classCache = mutable.Map[String, Class[_]]()
private val settings = new Settings()
  settings.deprecation.value = true // enable detailed deprecation warnings
  settings.unchecked.value = true // enable detailed unchecked warnings
  settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(target)
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  settings.classpath.append(getSourcePath())

  private val global = new Global(settings)
  private lazy val run = new global.Run
  val classLoader = new AbstractFileClassLoader(target, this.getClass.getClassLoader)
```

My testing environment is a system that uploads scala code and compiles and runs scala code. So I can't provide mcve. I submitted some scala programs that worked fine without importing jni, but whenever I tried to include jni code in my scala code, I got an error saying that scala.native was not found
Here is my program

```
class DllTest {

  @native def intMethod(n: Int): Int

  def loadLibrary(): Unit = {
    System.load("D:\\Idea\\scala_test\\libtest.dll")
  }
}
```

It is then imported into the embedded scala code

```
import rep.DllTest
  def test(ctx: ContractContext): ActionResult = {
    val s = new DllTest
    s.loadLibrary()
    print(s.intMethod(5))
    null
  }
```

Is scala-compiler.jar unable to compile native methods?
Moreover, the imported code works fine in the main system function, but scala-compiler.jar throws an error

After debugging, the code that throws the exception looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKvpH.png)

Comment: I could try to reproduce, firstly without scala-compiler.jar, secondly with it. Do you have an example of `libtest.dll` so that I could reproduce? Will this work on Linux (I'm on Ubuntu, not Windows). It seems there are some issues with classpath. You should compare classpath while not using scala-compiler.jar and while using it. It should work somehow with native methods since when you compile without scala-compiler.jar it's actually done by the same scala-compiler.jar, just it's not you who starts it manually.

Comment: Do you have any updates?